# Problem with synchronization in family queue ownership transfer and image layout transition in vulkan

Tags: layout, synchronization, vulkan

I am using a transfer queue to copy image data from a staging buffer to various images that later on I use in shaders as textures. The problem is that I get synchronization errors from validation layers (WRITE-AFTER-WRITE) and that image layout is not in correct layout. It seems like my transfer semaphore is not working correctly. I can render the whole scene if after the transfer I use vkQueueWaitIdle but this shouldnt be necessary if the barriers and the semaphore I am using are configured correctly. Basically I use a barrier to transition image format from VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_UNDEFINED to VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_DST_OPTIMAL, after that I issue the copy commands and then I use another barrier to release the images from transfer queue to graphics queue. During transfer queue submission I use a signal semaphore to notify graphics queue. In the final step I use a pipeline barrier in graphics queue to acquire the images. During that command submission I wait on the signal semaphore (as wait semaphore this time) in VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_2_FRAGMENT_SHADER_BIT stage.

Here is a snippet of my code

```cpp
std::vector<std::pair<VkImage, VkBufferImageCopy>> copy_instr;
copy_instr.reserve(textures.size());
std::vector<VkImageMemoryBarrier2> trf_opt_barriers;
trf_opt_barriers.reserve(textures.size());
std::vector<VkImageMemoryBarrier2> release_barriers;
release_barriers.reserve(textures.size());
std::vector<VkImageMemoryBarrier2> aquire_barriers;
aquire_barriers.reserve(textures.size());

vkWaitForFences(device->get_logical_device(), 1, &transfer_fence, VK_FALSE, UINT64_MAX);
vkResetFences(device->get_logical_device(), 1, &transfer_fence);
vkResetCommandPool(device->get_logical_device(), transfer_command_pool, 0);
vkResetCommandPool(device->get_logical_device(), graphics_command_pool, 0);
tb_pos = 0;
    
for (auto& texture : textures)
{
    upload_data(texture_upload_buffer, texture.data, tb_pos, texture.size);
    VkBufferImageCopy region = init::make_buffer_image_copy(tb_pos, 0, 0, { 0,0,0 }, texture.extent);
    tb_pos += texture.size;

    copy_instr.push_back({ texture.image ,region });

    trf_opt_barriers.push_back(init::make_image_mem_barrier2(texture.image, VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_UNDEFINED, VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_DST_OPTIMAL,
        VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_2_TOP_OF_PIPE_BIT, VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_2_TRANSFER_BIT, 0, VK_ACCESS_2_TRANSFER_WRITE_BIT));

    release_barriers.push_back(init::make_image_mem_barrier2(texture.image, VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_DST_OPTIMAL, VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_SHADER_READ_ONLY_OPTIMAL,
        VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_2_TRANSFER_BIT, 0, VK_ACCESS_2_TRANSFER_WRITE_BIT, 0, {VK_IMAGE_ASPECT_COLOR_BIT,0,1,0,1}, 2, 0));

    aquire_barriers.push_back(init::make_image_mem_barrier2(texture.image, VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_DST_OPTIMAL, VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_SHADER_READ_ONLY_OPTIMAL,
        0, VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_2_FRAGMENT_SHADER_BIT, 0, VK_ACCESS_2_SHADER_READ_BIT, { VK_IMAGE_ASPECT_COLOR_BIT,0,1,0,1 }, 2, 0));
}

const VkDependencyInfo trf_dep_info = init::dependancy_info(nullptr, 0, {}, {}, trf_opt_barriers);
const VkDependencyInfo shd_dep_info = init::dependancy_info(nullptr, 0, {}, {}, release_barriers);

const auto transfer_begin_info = init::command_buffer_begin_info();
vkBeginCommandBuffer(transfer_command_buffer, &transfer_begin_info);
vkCmdPipelineBarrier2(transfer_command_buffer, &trf_dep_info);
for (auto& [image, region] : copy_instr)
    vkCmdCopyBufferToImage(transfer_command_buffer, texture_upload_buffer.buffer, image, VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_DST_OPTIMAL, 1, &region);
vkCmdPipelineBarrier2(transfer_command_buffer, &shd_dep_info);
vkEndCommandBuffer(transfer_command_buffer);

const auto transfer_cmd_buffer_submit_info = init::command_buffer_submit_info(nullptr, transfer_command_buffer);
const auto transfer_semaphore_signal_info = init::semaphore_submit_info(nullptr, transfer_semaphore, 0, VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_2_BOTTOM_OF_PIPE_BIT);
const auto transfer_submit_info = init::submit_info2(nullptr, 0, { &transfer_cmd_buffer_submit_info, 1}, {}, {&transfer_semaphore_signal_info, 1});
vkQueueSubmit2(device->get_transfer_queue(), 1, &transfer_submit_info, transfer_fence);
vkQueueWaitIdle(device->get_transfer_queue());

const auto graphics_begin_info = init::command_buffer_begin_info();
const VkDependencyInfo aquire_dep_info = init::dependancy_info(nullptr, 0, {}, {}, aquire_barriers);
vkBeginCommandBuffer(graphics_command_buffer, &graphics_begin_info);
vkCmdPipelineBarrier2(graphics_command_buffer, &aquire_dep_info);
vkEndCommandBuffer(graphics_command_buffer);

const auto graphics_cmd_buffer_submit_info = init::command_buffer_submit_info(nullptr, graphics_command_buffer);
const auto graphics_semaphore_wait_info = init::semaphore_submit_info(nullptr, transfer_semaphore, 0, VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_2_FRAGMENT_SHADER_BIT);
const auto graphics_submit_info = init::submit_info2(nullptr, 0, { &graphics_cmd_buffer_submit_info, 1 }, { &graphics_semaphore_wait_info, 1 }, {});
vkQueueSubmit2(device->get_graphics_queue(), 1, &graphics_submit_info, VK_NULL_HANDLE);
```

I tried various stages/masks but I cannot do it work properly without vkQueueWaitIdle() call. Any hint were my error could be is appreciated!

Thanks